# Displaying page specific content

Tags: php, html

I am making a website with PHP and have encountered an issue.

- All my webpages `include` a footer, and I want to display data in the footer depending on the opened webpage, I found a very non-robust way of doing this.

  ```
  if( $CU == 'http://www.example.com' 
       || $CU == 'http://example/index.php'     
       || $CU == 'http://example/index.php/'    
       || $CU == 'http://example/')
  { 
  $display = "<p>Already registered? <a href='login.php'>Sign in</a></p>";
  }

  elseif( $CU == 'http://www.example/login.php' 
       || $CU == 'http://example.com/login.php' )
   { 
   $display = "<p>Forgotten your password? <a href='reset_password.php'>Reset</a> your password!</p>";
   }
  ```

**Question (edited):** What is a robust method of dynamically loading content based on the current file?

Comment: Wouldn't you decide which of those statements to display based on the user's status, and not which page they are on?

Comment: Well this is only for the register and login page, both of which the user would have to be logged out in order to see otherwise they get redirected..

Answer (score 0):

As per the nature of your question, I assume that not only you will want to **dinamically load content** in your footer, but also in other parts of your site. Moreover, you may also be interested in having a **robust methodology** for most of your code.

Here comes to play a [framework](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework).

Generally speaking, **frameworks** are a set of utilities aiming to provide you with built-in functions so you can develop your site/application in a more robust (among many other benefits) way.

In particular, you might be interested in learning about [PHP frameworks](http://phpframeworks.com/).

> Be aware. Turning your site from raw PHP into a framework might not be a trivial task. You should choose one first and learn how to use it. There is either a best or better framework, it depends on your needs and how to evaluate is out of the scope of this answer.

---

However, if you still want to achieve this with plain PHP, remember that there are many ways and there is not a best way, just **pros** and **cons** that *fit or not your needs*.

I would dinamically load (include) the footer according to your current URL. Again, how to achieve it is out of the scope of this answer as you will find better coverage in tutorials.

[This Content Management System example tutorial](http://alistapart.com/article/phpcms) explains pretty well how to achieve this in a simplistic -yet sort of  elegant- way and is straight php.